# How to call parameterized Constructor of Base class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have this header (Field)

```
class TicTacToeField{
protected:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> field;

public:
    TicTacToeField();
    TicTacToeField(std::vector<std::vector<int>> field);
};
```

And this header (Game) which inherits/extends the the class above (Field)

```
class TicTacToeGame : public TicTacToeField {
private:
    std::string player1_;
    std::string player2_;
    int currentPlayer_;
public:
    TicTacToeGame(std::string player1, std::string player2);
```

This is the constructor of the Field class

```
TicTacToeField::TicTacToeField(vector<vector<int>> field) {
    this->field = field;
}
```

**Here is my problem**

This is the constructor of my Game class

```
TicTacToeGame::TicTacToeGame(std::string player1, std::string player2) : TicTacToeField(std::vector<std::vector<int>> field)) {
    this->player1_ = player1;
    this->player2_ = player2;
    this->field = field;
    currentPlayer_ = 1;
```

But this here `TicTacToeField(std::vector<std::vector<int>> field))` is wrong and I actually don't know what I should write in the brackets... if I use the default constructor `TicTacToeField()` then it's fine but how can I use the parameterized one?

And how do I create a new object? I tried this in my main.cpp but it only works if I extend the default constructor...

`TicTacToeGame g("Player1", "Player2");`

Comment: Well, you obviously have to pass it a vector of a vector of ints. Wherever you get that vector is entirely up to you, and there is no sufficient information in the shown code to be able to say any further than that. Wherever you figure out you get this vector of vector of ints from, you get it, and then pass it to the parent class's constructor. Also, one question per question, please.

Comment: I know I have to pass a vector of a vector of ints and I create this in my Game.cpp and pass it and it works. But how can I pass it from the main.cpp? I am not sure how to call a paramzerized constructor in the main function

Comment: Only a subclass calls the superclass's constructor. If you need to pass something to the superclass's constructor, you pass it to the subclass' constructor, and it passes it to the superclass constructor. Your subclass's constructor already takes two parameters, player1 and player2. Add a third parameter, and have the constructor pass the new third parameter to the parent class's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> But this here `TicTacToeField(std::vector<std::vector<int>> field))`
>   is wrong [...]

You should be passing the *vector of vector of `int`s* to here. Meaning, the `TicTacToeGame` should have a parameter of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, which can later be passed to the constructor of the parent class `TicTacToeField`. Example

```
TicTacToeGame(std::string player1, std::string player2, std::vector<std::vector<int>> field = {})
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ provided as default arguments
   : TicTacToeField{ std::move(field) } // resources (preferably) can be moved, rather copy constructing them.
   , player1_{ std::move(player1) }     // Otherwise, pass by const reference
   , player2_{ std::move(player2) }
   , currentPlayer_{ 0 }
{}
```

Since you provide the parent constructor argument as [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments), now you have the following two options to construct the `TicTacToeGame`.

```
TicTacToeGame game{ "player1", "player2" };
// or pass std::vector<std::vector<int>>
TicTacToeGame game2{ "player1", "player2", {{1, 2, 3},{4, 5}} };
```

---

However, if you do not have `mField` available at the moment of constructing `TicTacToeGame`, you could either invoke the default constructor of `TicTacToeField` (i.e. parent class) or pass a default constructed `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to chose the parameterized constructor of the `TicTacToeField`.

```
TicTacToeGame(std::string player1, std::string player2)
   : TicTacToeField{ std::vector<std::vector<int>>{} }
   // or simply default constructor : TicTacToeField{}
   , player1_{ std::move(player1) }
   , player2_{ std::move(player2) }
   , currentPlayer_{ 0 }
{}
```

---

A couple of suggestions:

- Provide different names to the constructor arguments and the members
  of the class.
- Use [member initializer
  lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)
  to initialize the members, rather constructing the class and
  initializing the members as you did.

```
class TicTacToeField
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> mField;  // class member `mField`
public:
   TicTacToeField(std::vector<std::vector<int>> field) // parameter `field`
      : mField{ std::move(field) }        // member initializer lists
   {}
};
```